# How to create more Monster with different shemes

Tags: java, extends

Hello I'm currently working on my homework creating a Text Based RPG.
I have created a `Monster.class` which contains the Monster properties.
My Task is to create multiple Monsters with different properties (different Atk pattern). The Problem is that I should use different Classes which extends the Monster Class. I don't know how to create them using the Monster.class.

```
public class Monster extends Characters {

    public Monster() {
        this(160, 45, 0.6);
    }

    public Monster(int Hp, int atk, double hitChance){
        this.Hp = Hp;
        this.atk = atk;
        this.hitChance = hitChance;
    }

    public int attack(Player p) {
        if (Math.random() <= hitChance) {
            int damage = (int) (atk * (Math.random() + 1.0));
            p.takeDamage(damage);
            return damage;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("Gegner -- HP %d -- ATK %d%n",Hp, atk);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to define what an "Atk pattern" is.  There could be several answers to this question and it depends on the actual assignment was.  Please also don't use abbreviations because we aren't in your class and don't know what those abbreviations mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just extend the Monster class and Override the attack method.

```
public class Zombie extends Monster{

 public Zombie(int Hp, int atk, double hitChance){
    super(hp,atk,hitChance);
 }
 @Override
 public int attack(Player p) {
   // new awesome pattern
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
public class NewMonster extends Monster{

  public NewMonster(int hp, int atk, double hitChance){
     super(hp, atk, hitChance);
  }
}
```